# Swift- Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following Swift code where I am sending a POST request to a webserver and receiving a value back. The error that I receive is on the second to last line saying "Use of unresolved identifier"

```
func download_request() -> String {
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://url.com/read.php")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    let paramString = "data=name"
    request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) {

        (let location, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        let urlContents = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: location!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

     }

    task.resume()
    return urlContents
}
```

How would I fix this error? I think that it means that I cannot use urlContents outside of the let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) { } but how would I declare the variable so that I can use it outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring `urlContents` outside of the `session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) { }` block. Like so:

```
func download_request() -> String? {
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://url.com/read.php")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var urlContents: NSString?

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    let paramString = "data=name"
    request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) {

        (let location, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        urlContents = try? NSString(contentsOfURL: location!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
           print("Error")
           return
        }

     }

    task.resume()
    return (urlContents as! String)
}
```

Then when you need to use `urlContents` unwrap it with an if let binding

```
if let contents = download_request() {
    //Use safely unwrapped contents
}
```

Comment: This fixed the error, however, I now get a different error when building and running: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: The code fixed that problem but the if statement that lets me us the unwrapped urlContents is not running (as tested by else statement).

Comment: Try checking `print(contents)` inside the if let statement. If this returns `nil`, then you may want to check you link as it is probably returning `nil` for content. Also where did you put the if let statement? @DanielZam

Comment: I put the if let statement inside of a button press

Comment: What are you trying to download?  @DanielZam.

Comment: I found an issue in my code that I fixed but now I am receiving the same error, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the return (urlContents as! String) line

Comment: Instead of return (urlContents as! String) I had return (urlContents as? String). The second one didn't produce an error but when I printed contents later, nothing printed.

Comment: what type of data are you downloading? @DanielZam `downloadTaskWithRequest`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114675/discussion-between-ike10-and-daniel-zam).

Comment: I'm just sending data and receiving a string from an echo in a php page.

Answer (score 0):

You could make return type `optional` like below

```
func download_request() -> String? {
     var urlContents: String?
     ....
     ....
     let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) {

        (let location, let response, let error) in
        ...
        ...
        ...
        guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
       urlContents = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: location!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String
        guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return urlContents
}
```

And call the method like

```
 if let request = download_request() {
     //do anything with your request
 }
```

Suggesting you to rename your method properly since you are returning the downloaded data not the request.

And this is not the correct way to get your downloaded data back as a return to the method since the `completionHandler` will be called once the operation is done so `urlContents` will be nil. Hence create another method which takes `String` as input and call it within the `completionHandler` of `downloadTaskWithRequest`